# How to link plain html with plain php without downloading the file

Tags: php, html

I want to link plain html (no apache, no xampp) with plain php without downloading the php file. Is this possible?

In the future I want to link my website with a database using mySQL but now it just downloads the php file.

Comment: Okay... but does it work when I upload my files to the website provider? Or do I need to install something there too?

Comment: You need a webserver which supports PHP. If you are using a dedicated server or a VPS then you need to make sure one is installed. If you aren't then you need to select a hosting service which provides you with that.

Comment: It works now with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

...no, to execute PHP (via a web page) you need a webserver which is set up with the PHP interpreter installed too. It's not clear why you want to avoid that.

The solution is to just install XAMPP (or similar) and get on with your task. You'll need that as well anyway when you come to start working with a database.